# How to delete files if they contain "setup" in their name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, del

I was trying to make a batch file that deletes files that contain `setup` in their names but can't solve a problem with the batch code. Here's what I tried:

```
echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /R %completepath% %%G IN (*.exe) DO (
set "file=%%~nG"
@rem completepath
If not "!file!"=="!file:setu=!" (
    del !file!
    echo SKDISUFISUIDAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

) else (
    echo Dont  contain it
)
)
ENDLOCAL

pause
```

But it shows an error:

> ```
> Could Not Find C:\Users\MessaIsland5\Downloads\tsetup-x64.3.3.0
> ```

Comment: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `del /?` and read the output help. There can be used simply `del /A /F /Q /S "%completepath%\*setup*.exe"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you try to delete the file by base name (no extension due to `%%~nG`), but you must specify its full path/name. So use `del "%%~G"` instead of `del !file!`:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Also quote the root path:
for /R "%completepath%" %%G in (*.exe) do (
    rem // Use proper indentation herein.
    set "file=%%~nG"
    if not "!file!"=="!file:setup=!" (
        rem /* `%%~G` will contain the full file path;
        rem    `/F` defines to delete write-protected files too;
        rem    `/A` also includes hidden and system files: */
        del /F /A "%%~G"
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

However, there is a much simpler approach, namely a single [`del`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html) command line:

```cmd
del /S /Q /F /A "%completepath%\*setup*.exe"
```